# This content cannot be displayed in a frame

Tags: java, html, meta-tags

I am getting Error as below :

> This content cannot be displayed in a frame

To help protect the security of information you enter into this website, the publisher of this content does not allow it to be displayed in a frame.

**What you can try:**
Open this content in a new window

& the content opens up in another tab. i want to load the page in the same tab as opening not instead of directing to other page.One thing I found is, urls of both the pages are quite different.

1st page - https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:23000/cddtweb/DDSMain.jsp

2nd page - https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:23000/cddtweb/DDSEntitlements.jsp

Could i get some help here to solve this issue please.

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/18157)

Comment: formatting the text

Answer (score 2):

What you describe is probably caused by a security feature called [X-Frame-Options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options) implemented on the server of the frame content provider to protect from [clickjacking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clickjacking).

As stated in the first link, this feature is supported by all major browsers. **If you don't have access to the application which generated the frame content, there is nothing you can do about it (to my best knowledge).**

Depending on your use-case you might be able to fetch the frame content, tweak it and then output it directly into your page without `<iframe/>`. This method is more described in [an article by Crhis Duell](https://blog.elev.io/getting-around-the-x-frame-options-to-sameorigin-issue/) (although for PHP, but you should get the point).

If you have access to the application that generates the frame content, you need to set `X-Frame-Options` HTTP header with a proper value (e.g. `X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN` if the frame uses the same domain).

Comment: I do have access to the frame generated. what can i implement to make the frame work?

Comment: I have updated my answer. Just to be perfectly clear: you need access to the system that generates the frame content. For JSP sth. like `<% response.addHeader("X-Frame-Options", "SAMEORIGIN"); %>` should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your app accessible in iframe of some other browser then you have to set **Content-Security-Policy** directive as frame-ancester and parent browser URL(for whitelisting)
***Example:***   Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors https://example.com
in the response header you will see **content-security-policy: frame-ancestors  https://example.com https://example1.com**
This works for most of the browsers except IE11. For IE11 you have to set **X-Content-Security-Policy**: parent url.
Example: **x-content-security-policy: https://example.com https://example1.com**